# Basic Table View Issue

Tags: swift, debugging, tableview

I'm fairly new to Swift and I'm trying to set up a super simple table view and nothing I've tried has worked.  It builds with no issue but my table is invisible on the simulator.  What am I doing wrong?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

var currentNames: Array = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", "Name6", "Name7", "Name8", "Name9", "Name10"]
var currentDays: Array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return currentNames.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let currDays = currentDays[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = currentNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(currDays)
    return(cell)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: So what is `currentWorkoutNames.count`? Your image cannot be found, anyway.

Comment: have you set the function numberofsections to return atleast 1?

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm you have used the below lines in ViewDidLoad after creating an outlet of tableView

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

as

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     tableView.delegate = self
     tableView.dataSource = self
 }

var currentNames: Array = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", 
    "Name6", "Name7", "Name8", "Name9", "Name10"]
var currentDays: Array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return currentWorkoutNames.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let currDays = currentDays[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = currentNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(currDays)
    return(cell)
}
```

Comment: I just did but still have the same problem.  Something isn't right. :/

Comment: Does currentWorkoutNames array has data?, Cant see it declared anywhere

Comment: That was a typo when I changed the variable names to make them less confusing for stack overflow. I changed the original post. All the variables are declared and initialized with values.  I'm just so confounded by how this tableview won't appear.